# Subsets and element examples that I wanted to double check with

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I wanted to double check these practice problems to see if they were done correctly so as to reaffirm my understanding of subsets and elements. The questions are as follows:

"Let $A = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10\}$ Given an example of two sets $S$ and $B$ such that $S \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A)$, $\mid S \mid = 4$, $B \in S$ and $\mid B \mid = 2$.

The answer I had for this was $S = \{ \{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{4,5\}\}$, $B = \{4,5\}$. Hence this should satisfy the conditions right ?

The second questions is:

"Give an example of two sets $A$ and $B$ such that $A \cap \mathcal{P}(A) \in B$ and $\mathcal{P}(A) \subseteq A \cup B$.

The answer was $A = \{1,\{1\}\}$ and $\mathcal{P}(A) = \{\emptyset, \{1\},\{\{1\}\},\{1,\{1\}\}\}$. As a result, $A \cap \mathcal{P}(A) = \{\{1\}\}$ and $B = \{\{\{1\}\}, \{\emptyset\},\emptyset,\{\{\{1\}\}\},\{\{1,\{1\}\}\}\}$

Do my examples look correct ?

A confirmation would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer to the first question works.

For the second question, however, it's not the case that $\mathcal{P}(A) \subseteq A \cup B$. For instance, $\{1,\{1\}\} \in \mathcal{P}(A)$, but $\{1,\{1\}\}$ is in not an element of $A$ or $B$. You could instead set $B=\mathcal{P}(A)$. Then certainly $\mathcal{P}(A) \subseteq A \cup B$, and as you computed, $A \cap \mathcal{P}(A)=\{\{1\}\} \in \mathcal{P}(A)=B$.

Comment: Oh yes that is correct. I overlooked that part as another check, would the following be an example of $A \subset B, A \in B, \text{ and } A \subset \mathcal{P}(B)$: If $A = \{\{1\}\}$ then $B = \{\{1\},\{\{1\}\},\{\{\{1\}\}\}\}$ ? or would the latter case of $A = \{\{1\}\}$, $B = \{1,\{1\},\{\{1\}\}\}$ be fulfilling the condition ? Thank you for the advice

Comment: Both of your examples satisfy $A \subset B$ and $A \in B$, but only one satisfies $A \subset \mathcal{P}(B)$. Given $A=\{\{1\}\}$, to have $A \subset \mathcal{P}(B)$ means $\{\{1\}\}\subset \mathcal{P}(B)$, i.e., $\{1\} \in \mathcal{P}(B)$. Now which choice of $B$ is correct?

Comment: Ah it is the latter right ?

Comment: Indeed, it is the latter.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you're asking, and it's best to ask a new question rather than add more questions in the comments.